# Copying with wildcard

Tags: linux, ant, copy, exec

I am trying to copy the content of a folder with `ant` and need to keep the privileges of the files within.

I used the following `ant` code to do so:

```
<exec executable="cp">
    <arg line="-pr env/* ." />
</exec>
```

When I try the command manually it works, but when I run the ant file I get the following error:

```
deploy.add.op:
     [exec] cp: cannot access env/*
     [exec] Result: 2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ant can't expand the `*` wildcard. You need to copy each sub folder on it's own:

```
<exec executable="cp">
    <arg line="-pr env/sub1 ." />
</exec>

<exec executable="cp">
    <arg line="-pr env/sub2 ." />
</exec>

..
```

or if this is unsufficient you may spawn a bash:

```
<exec executable="bash">
    <arg line="-c 'cp -pr env/* .'" />
</exec>
```

but the latter will work only on systems which having bash installed.

Also have a look at `rsync` instead of `cp`. Might be better because it can cleanup older files. However using tools like `bash` and `rsync` will make your script bound to *NIX systems.